# Behaviour of Num Lock

Tags: command-line, keyboard, numpad

I have a ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

My Num Lock was ON, and I accidentally pressed a key on numberpad.

And I noticed that
the keys change functionality, like,

```
8 - up arrow
4 - left arrow
6 - right arrow
2 - down arrow
```

When I press 3 on number pad, it types ~(tilde character)

This behaviour is only on the command-line, and not on any text-editor.

I want to turn these keys completely off. How to do that?

I was having windows earlier, windows was not having this behaviour. So, its not hardware related I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is standard behavior on a US Keyboardlayout. Moreover, the mapping of the arrows should be the same even on windows (I have a microsoft keyboard that even has the arrows printed on the respective Numpad keys.

NumLock is not supposed to turn the Numpad off, it is supposed to toggle its behavior.

Comment: seems right to me !!